# Unable to filter out results based on "missing" field in elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, elasticsearch, tire

I am using tire-0.4.2 to interact with elasticsearch in my rails application (uses mongodb database and mongoid for interacting with mongdb). I have a post model which has a spam document embedded in it.

post.rb

```
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps 

..
embeds one :spam, as: :spammable
...
```

spam.rb

```
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
embedded_in :spammable, polymorphic: true
field :needs_approval, type: Boolean, default: false
field :is_spam, type: Time

has_and_belongs_to_many :request_spam_by, :class_name => "User"

field :request_spam, type: Boolean, default: false
```

I want to get all the posts which have no spam document: Here is the tire query

```
Post.tire.search(:load => :true, page: self.page, per_page: Post::PER_PAGE) do |pf|
    pf.query{ |query| query.string self.search_text } unless search_text.blank?
    pf.filter(:missing, :field => 'spam')
    pf.filter(:term, :college_id => self.college.id)
    pf.filter(:term, :user_id => self.user.id)
    pf.filter(:missing, :field => 'spam' )
    pf.filter(:terms, :user_type => self.user_type) unless self.user_type.blank?
    pf.filter(:range, :created_at => {:gte => self.from_time}) unless self.from_time.blank?
    pf.filter(:range, :created_at => {:lte => self.to_time}) unless self.to_time.blank?
    pf.sort{|s| s.by :updated_at, self.sort_order}
end
```

generated elasticsearch query:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/development_posts/post/_search?     from=0&load=true&page=1&per_page=10&size=10&pretty=true" -d '{"sort":[{"updated_at":"desc"}],"filter":{"and":[{"missing":{"field":"spam"}},{"term":{"college_id":"4fb424a5addf32296f00013a"}},{"missing":{"field":"spam"}},{"range":{"created_at":{"gte":"2012-06-05T00:00:00+05:30"}}},{"range":{"created_at":{"lte":"2012-06-05T23:59:59+05:30"}}}]},"size":10,"from":0}'
```

The results of the query gives me the documents in which spam exists even though I am searching only for documents which have spam document missing. I don't know what is the mistake I am doing. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `missing` on an object level only actual fields that get indexed.

If there is a field that is always present in a spam object then you could set the missing filter on "spam.always_there" which isn't quite as nice but should work

```
 pf.filter(:or, [
    {:missing => { :field => 'spam.needs_approval'}},
    {:term => {'spam.needs_approval' => false}}])
```

Should select documents where that field is either false or missing (if I remember correctly by default null and missing are the same thing so watch out there)

Comment: ok if I want to get all the post documents whose spam documment's field 'needs approval' is false as well as those post documents which don't have spam document at all. In this case what should my query be like?